# Optaplanner VRP remove customer from working solution

Tags: java, optaplanner

Based on this [example](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#problemFactChangeExample) from cloud balancing problem, I'm trying to remove customer from a working solution as follows:

```
Location toBeRemovedLocation = customerToBeRemoved.getLocation();
Location lookUpWorkingObject = (Location) scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(toBeRemovedLocation);
scoreDirector.beforeProblemFactRemoved(lookUpWorkingObject);
routingSolution.getLocationList().remove(lookUpWorkingObject);
scoreDirector.afterProblemFactRemoved(lookUpWorkingObject);

Customer workingCustomer=(Customer) scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(customerToBeRemoved);

for (Customer customer : routingSolution.getCustomerList()) {
    nextCustomer=customer.getNextCustomer();
    if (nextCustomer==workingCustomer) {
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
        customer.setNextCustomer(null);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
    }
}

scoreDirector.beforeEntityRemoved(workingCustomer);
routingSolution.getCustomerList().remove(workingCustomer);
scoreDirector.afterEntityRemoved(workingCustomer);
scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners();
```

I got this exception as a result:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity
>   (Customer--6361356485874019865) has a variable (previousStandstill)
>   with value (Customer--9027426768799526425) which has a
>   sourceVariableName variable (nextCustomer) with a value (null) which
>   is not that entity.Verify the consistency of your input problem for
>   that sourceVariableName variable

After that, I tried to also `setPreviousStandstill` to `null`:

```
scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");
customer.setPreviousStandstill(null);
scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");
```

But, I received:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity
>   (Customer--6361368382933429785) has a variable (previousStandstill)
>   with value (Customer--9027434800388369945) which has a
>   sourceVariableName variable (nextCustomer) with a value (null) which
>   is not that entity.Verify the consistency of your input problem for
>   that sourceVariableName variable.

Need help, please.

Comment: @Geofrey De Smet

Answer (score 0):

Customers in VRP are chained/linked, if you currently have a chain [Customer1, Customer2, Customer3]

```
- Customer1: nextCustomer = Customer2
- Customer2: nextCustomer = Customer2, prevStandstill = Customer1
- Customer3: prevStandstill = Customer2
```

and you're trying to remove Customer2 from it, you have to fix both previous and next elements:

```
- Customer1: nextCustomer = Customer3
- Customer2: nextCustomer = null, prevStandstill = null
- Customer3: prevStandStill = Customer1
```