# Optaplanner remove customer from working VRP solution

Tags: java, optaplanner

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913276/optaplanner-vrp-remove-customer-from-working-solution) i tried the following:

```
public void doFactChange() {
    Location toBeRemovedLocation = customerToBeRemoved.getLocation();
    Location lookUpWorkingObject = (Location) scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(toBeRemovedLocation);
    scoreDirector.beforeProblemFactRemoved(lookUpWorkingObject);
    routingSolution.getLocationList().remove(lookUpWorkingObject);
    scoreDirector.afterProblemFactRemoved(lookUpWorkingObject);
    Customer workingCustomer = (Customer) scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(customerToBeRemoved);

    for (Customer customer : routingSolution.getCustomerList()) {
        while (customer != null) {
            if (customer == workingCustomer) {
                if (customer.getPreviousStandstill() != null) {
                    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");
                    customer.getPreviousStandstill().setNextCustomer(customer.getNextCustomer());

                    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");
                }

                scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
                customer.getNextCustomer().setPreviousStandstill(customer.getPreviousStandstill());
                scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
            }
            customer = customer.getNextCustomer();
        }
    }

    scoreDirector.beforeEntityRemoved(workingCustomer);
    routingSolution.getCustomerList().remove(workingCustomer);
    scoreDirector.afterEntityRemoved(workingCustomer);
    scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners();
}
```

Note: `customerToBeRemoved` is an instance object that's created before calling `doFactChange()`

But I received the following exception even before calling `scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners`

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity (Customer--9048381398840634905) has a variable (previousStandstill) with value (Customer--9070671076516032025) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextCustomer) with a value (Customer-8518512081385427431) which is not that entity.
>   Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.

Another question:

I tried to remove the entity directly as follows:

```
public void doFactChange() {
    Location toBeRemovedLocation = customerToBeRemoved.getLocation();
    Location lookUpWorkingObject = (Location) scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(toBeRemovedLocation);
    scoreDirector.beforeProblemFactRemoved(lookUpWorkingObject);
    routingSolution.getLocationList().remove(lookUpWorkingObject);
    scoreDirector.afterProblemFactRemoved(lookUpWorkingObject);
    Customer workingCustomer = (Customer) scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(customerToBeRemoved);

    scoreDirector.beforeEntityRemoved(workingCustomer);
    routingSolution.getCustomerList().remove(workingCustomer);
    scoreDirector.afterEntityRemoved(workingCustomer);
    scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners();
}
```

Is that valid?

Comment: @ Geoffrey De Smet, your kind support.

Answer (score 2):

This method works fine with optaplanner VRP example using easy, incremental and drl score calculators:

```
public void removeRandomCustomer()
{
    doProblemFactChange(scoreDirector -> {
        VehicleRoutingSolution solution = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();
        int rnd = 4; //select a random customer
        if (solution.getCustomerList().size() > rnd)
        {
            Customer customer = solution.getCustomerList().get(rnd);
            scoreDirector.beforeEntityRemoved(customer);
            removeCustomer(solution, customer);
            scoreDirector.afterEntityRemoved(customer);
            scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners();
        }
    });
}

private void removeCustomer(VehicleRoutingSolution solution, Customer customer)
{
    Standstill anchor = customer.getPreviousStandstill();
    Customer nextCustomer = customer.getNextCustomer();
    //anchor shouldn't be null in an initialized solution
    if (anchor != null)
        anchor.setNextCustomer(nextCustomer);
    if (nextCustomer != null)
        nextCustomer.setPreviousStandstill(anchor);
    solution.getCustomerList().remove(customer);
}
```

Edit:

Alternative approach for shadow variables with easy/incremental scoring:

```
private void removeCustomer(ScoreDirector<VehicleRoutingSolution> scoreDirector, VehicleRoutingSolution solution, Customer removeCustomer)
{
    final Customer customer = scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(removeCustomer);
    Standstill anchor = customer.getPreviousStandstill();
    Customer nextCustomer = customer.getNextCustomer();

    //scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(anchor, "nextCustomer");
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");    //sets anchor.nextCustomer=null
    customer.setPreviousStandstill(null);
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");
    //scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(anchor, "nextCustomer");
    if(nextCustomer!=null)
    {
        //scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(nextCustomer, "previousStandstill");  //sets customer.nextCustomer=null
        nextCustomer.setPreviousStandstill(anchor);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(nextCustomer, "previousStandstill");
        //scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
    }

    scoreDirector.beforeEntityRemoved(customer);
    //clone customer list
    ArrayList<Customer> changedList = new ArrayList<>(solution.getCustomerList());
    solution.setCustomerList(changedList);
    solution.getCustomerList().remove(customer);
    scoreDirector.afterEntityRemoved(customer);
    scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners();  //sets customer.vehicle=null, sets all nextCustomer.vehicle=null

}
```

The solution should be in a valid state now but you'll probably have to fix the incremental scoring (easy score is fine because `doProblemFactChange()` recalculates it automatically), perhaps by removing the retraction in `VehicleRoutingIncrementalScoreCalculator.beforeEntityRemoved()`. If everything else fails you could first move the customer to the end of the chain and remove it from there.

Comment: Not working, below exception occurs: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity (Customer--9070677347168284185) has a variable (previousStandstill) with value (Customer--9097931491641781785) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextCustomer) with a value (null) which is not that entity.
Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.

Comment: That's a bit strange. Did you change anything else, perhaps in the `doProblemFactChange()` method? The posted code was tested with VRP example from optaplanner-distibution-7.5.0.Final and it works with both running and stopped solver.

Comment: how it worked without calling beforeVariableChanged and afterVariableChanged on scoreDirector ?

Comment: I suspect that Grudolf's approach is correct, but that Java Player's IllegalStateException is other complexity he added earlier which means remoteCustomer can't be blindly copy-pasted (or it could also be existing, unrelated invalid state).

Comment: Ok Geoffrey, if we ignored that exception and looked at the structure of the method, what's wrong with it?