# Optaplanner VRPTW "Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable"

Tags: java, optaplanner

```
The entity (AAA) has a variable (previousStandstill) with value (BBB) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextCustomer) with a value (AAA) which is not that entity.
Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.
```

When I resume my process of solving, it caused an error like above. When I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47943037/optaplanner-remove-customer-from-working-vrp-solution/47970539) problem, the first (AAA) and second (AAA) is different. But in my problem, both (AAA) is the same. What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `solve()` check if your data is correct. So that if AAA.previousStandstill = BBB that then BBB.nextCustomer = AAA.

Comment: Yes I already check the data and the data is correct